# How to pass data from user control to main control in wpf

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpf-4.0

I have status bar control in the main winodw. I have a user control placed in the main window.My user conrtorl has buttons .

say if i click the button in the user control ,I need to update the main window status bar .

I am following MVVM pattern. I am not sure how to achive this. I am beginner in wpf.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use **Dependency Property** to send something to Main Control from **UserControl**.

For eg: If you want to change the text of a textblock present in the Main Window from a button Click present in USerControl.

You need to bind your DependencyProperty to the TextBlock TEXT property to reflect the change and your USERCONTROL must Implement INotifyPropertyChange

**Make this DependencyProperty in your UserControl**

```
 public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("WriteText", typeof(string), typeof(UserControlnameSpace)) //Write Namespace of your UserControl where I mentioned

        public string WriteText
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(TextProperty ); }
            set
            {
                SetValue(TextProperty , value);
            }
        }
```

**ButtonClick event present in USERCONTROL**

```
public void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
WriteText="Hie"; //Write what you want to display on MainWindow.
}
```

**ViewModel**:-

```
private string _txtContent;

        public string TxtContent
        {
            get
            {
                return _txtContent;
            }

            set
            {
                _txtContent = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("TxtContent");
            }
        }
```

**Main Window**:-

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding TxtContent,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Where you are including your UserControl:-Include this property

```
<UserControl WriteText={Binding TxtContent Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you please give mesome code sample which i can reuse.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the DataContext(viewmodel) of the user control same as that of Main Window. Keep a property in viewModel and Bind that Property in the user control. So whenever anything changes in the Control that property will automatically be updated in the View Model which can be used by the Main

Comment: in your case your if usercontrol is being made by mvvm pattern then it will create a problem..

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that the usercontrol works with its own viewmodel. The main windows has a main controller which is responsible to initialize a Status bar messenger service and the user control view model uses that service.

User control's view model is bound to the button's actions via RelayCommand and on executing action it uses the status bar service to update the status.

This is enable your status bar on the main window to work with multiple user controls/pages of your application.